# How do I log the helpful exceptions in error.log that come when debug > 0

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

When Debug > 0 then I get meaningfull exception messages, when I switch debug = 0 then I just get HttpStatus codes and a simple message. I would like to log the meaningfull exception messages that I get when debug > 0 when I am in production.

Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 1):

you can use custom exception handler following will be helpful to you

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html

http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Common-Tasks-With-CakePHP/Logging.html